# Nuxt 3 unable to preload css

Tags: github-pages, nuxtjs3, preload, static-site-generation, jamstack

I am building a static site with Nuxt 3, deployed & hosted to Github Pages.

I added a dynamic route to my static site under pages/features/[id].vue. However when viewing this page on my github static hosting, I receive a 500 error message:

```
Unable to preload CSS for https://pierpaolo01.github.io/vidicrowd-website/assets/_id_.3d21884c.css
```

With the following errors in my console

[My console errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwohG.png)

I cannot wrap my head around what is going wrong here,

The 404 files are present in the build folder in github pages, and locally works well.

Here is my nuxt config along with my project on github:

Nuxt config: https://github.com/Pierpaolo01/vidicrowd-website/blob/main/nuxt.config.ts
Nuxt project: https://github.com/Pierpaolo01/vidicrowd-website

Comment: The problem seems to be with GitHub pages, I hosted the exact same code on Netlify static hosting and works perfect,